# Error converting string to dictionary object

Tags: json, ipython

I am converting the Json string into a Python dictionary object and I get the following error for the below code:

```
    import json

    path = 'data2012-03-16.txt'

    records = [json.loads(line) for line in open(path)]
```

Error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 6: invalid start byte

Comment: Can you provide also the content of the file?

Comment: Its a text file, the first line of json file is

        '{ "a": "Mozilla\\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\\/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\\/17.0.963.78 Safari\\/535.11", "c": "US", "nk": 1, "tz": "America\\/New_York", "gr": "MA", "g": "A6qOVH", "h": "wfLQtf", "l": "orofrog", "al": "en-US,en;q=0.8", "hh": "1.usa.gov", "r": "http:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/l\\/7AQEFzjSi\\/1.usa.gov\\/wfLQtf", "u": "http:\\/\\/www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\\/pubmed\\/22415991", "t": 1331923247, "hc": 1331822918, "cy": "Danvers", "ll": [ 42.576698, -70.954903 ] }\r\n'

Answer (score 0):

few suggestion-

1. Maybe the encoding of the file is not valid? try to open it in notepad++ and change the encoding.
2. Are you sure your json file is well formatted? try open it in json parser and check it.
3. Why you got error with byte 0x92 in position 6 what is in this index of your file? maybe you have problem with all the \/ issue, try to replace it with other letters and check if it is working. beside, you can use the elimination way and try to open other file with the same code.After that work open thin version of this file etc.